# Unknown column '<name>' in 'where clause'

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have a connection with a database table, called user, where I want to get the text from "todo". But I keep getting the "unknown column" error.

This is the Code I have so far:

```
 "SELECT `todo` FROM `user` WHERE `username` LIKE `" + _name+ "`"
```

Note: I'm a starter with sql, so please be specific.

Comment: Wrong quotes in the LIKE clause (unless you mean to refer to a table) instead: `LIKE '" + _name + "'"` - Also consider a parameterized query to avoid SQL injection problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table name and column name only enclosed by backticks not for string values .so remove backticks in where clause near like and add single quotes for string  values.

```
"SELECT `todo` FROM `user` WHERE `username` LIKE '" + _name+ "'"
```